# error de captacion de textView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, android-recyclerview, concatenación

soy nueva en este campo de la programación y recibo este error cuando invoco putExtra para obtener datos de  distintas actividades de mi app y concatenarlo en una sola actividad final dentro  la misma aplicación.
utilizo el lenguaje java de android studio.
he mirado hecho bastante buscadas  pero  sin solución.

le dejo el código.

Aqui mi logcat:

```
2021-07-15 13:34:13.921 20906-20906/? E/ralexpressstor: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-07-15 13:34:14.275 20906-20906/com.example.generalexpressstore E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
2021-07-15 13:34:16.568 20906-20906/com.example.generalexpressstore E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.generalexpressstore, PID: 20906
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.generalexpressstore.RecyclerClasses.ServiceSuplementaireRecycler$MyViewHolder.onClick(ServiceSuplementaireRecycler.java:158)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7161)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:818)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27677)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

aqui el RecyclerView de partida:

```
public class ServiceSuplementaireRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServiceSuplementaireRecycler.MyViewHolder> {


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textV;
        CardView cardView;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


            textV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textV);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Intent intent;


            switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                case 0:
                     intent = new Intent(context, ServiceActivity.class);
                     break;



                case 1:

                    intent = new Intent(context, FinalActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("1", DonneesDeAcheteurActivity.textViewNom.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("2", DonneesDeAcheteurActivity.textViewPhone.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("3", AgenceDepartActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("4", AgenceArriveeActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("5", DateActivity.textViewDate.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("6", /*"Votre voyage est prevu pour le" + "" +*/ DateActivity.textViewDate.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("7", HeureActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("8", SiegeActivity.textView2.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("9", MonaiePayeActivity.okay2.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("10", MonaiePayeActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("11", MoyenPayementActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("12", TransfertActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("13", SiegeActivity.textSetSelection.getText().toString());

                    intent.putExtra("14", TaxiArondissementActivity.textView.getText().toString());

                    intent.putExtra("15", MotoArondissementActivity.textView.getText().toString());

                    intent.putExtra("16", ColisLegerNationalActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("17", ColisLegerNationalActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("18", ColisLegerNationalActivity.textView2U.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("19", ColisLegerNationalActivity.textView2D.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("20", ColisLegerNationalActivity.textView2T.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("21", ColisLegerNationalActivity.textView2Q.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("22", ColisLegerNationalActivity.textView2C.getText().toString());

                    intent.putExtra("23", ColisInternationalActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("24", ColisInternationalActivity.textView2U.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("25", ColisInternationalActivity.textView2D.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("26", ColisInternationalActivity.textView2T.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("27", ColisInternationalActivity.textView2Q.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("28", ColisInternationalActivity.textView2C.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("29", ColisInternationalActivity.textView2Si.getText().toString());

                    intent.putExtra("30", CargoNationalActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("31", CargoNationalActivity.textView2.getText().toString());

                     break;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + getAdapterPosition());
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

aqui la class que recibe al RecyclerView:

```
     public class ServiceSuplementaireActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    ServiceSuplementaireRecycler serviceSuplementaireRecycler;


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static TextView textView;
    TextView textV;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_suplementaire);


        textV = findViewById(R.id.textV);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);




        List<ServiceSuplementaireRecycler.Ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<>();

        ticketList.add(new ServiceSuplementaireRecycler.Ticket(R.drawable.ok_emoji, "OUI"));
        ticketList.add(new ServiceSuplementaireRecycler.Ticket(R.drawable.non_emoji, "NON"));

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        // recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, bienvenueList, textV);
        serviceSuplementaireRecycler = new ServiceSuplementaireRecycler(this, ticketList, textV);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(serviceSuplementaireRecycler);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



    }
}
```

Aqui el xml de la class que recibe RecyclerView:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.ServiceSuplementaireActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Voulez-Vous solicitez un service suplementaire"
        android:textColor="@color/noir_fonce"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Aqui la class que recibe los intent.putExtras:

```
public class ConcatenacionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    

    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    Button btnConfirmationDoneesAchats, btnDechargeTicket;


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static TextView textViewPrincipal;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static TextView  textView3;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_concatenacion);


    

        nestedScrollView = findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
        textViewPrincipal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        btnDechargeTicket =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDechargeTicket);

        btnConfirmationDoneesAchats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ConcatenacionActivity.this, ImpressionNomsVoyageursActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        btnConfirmationDoneesAchats = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmationDoneesAchats);

        btnDechargeTicket.setOnClickListener(v -> {


            Intent intent = new Intent(ConcatenacionActivity.this, ModeConfirmationTicketActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        });



       Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String valor1 = bundle.getString("1" );
        String valor2 = bundle.getString("2" );
        String valor3 = bundle.getString("3" );
        String valor4 = bundle.getString("4" );
        String valor5 = bundle.getString("5" );
        String valor6 = bundle.getString("6" );
        String valor7 = bundle.getString("7" );
        String valor8 = bundle.getString("8" );
        String valor9 = bundle.getString("9" );
        String valor10 = bundle.getString("10" );
        String valor11 = bundle.getString("11" );

        String valor12 = bundle.getString("12" );
        String valor13 = bundle.getString("13" );
        String valor14 = bundle.getString("14" );
        String valor15 = bundle.getString("15" );
        String valor16 = bundle.getString("16" );
        String valor17 = bundle.getString("17");
        String valor18 = bundle.getString("18" );
        String valor19 = bundle.getString("19" );
        String valor20 = bundle.getString("20" );
        String valor21 = bundle.getString("21" );

        String valor22 = bundle.getString("22" );
        String valor23 = bundle.getString("23" );
        String valor24 = bundle.getString("24" );
        String valor25 = bundle.getString("25" );
        String valor26 = bundle.getString("26" );
        String valor27 = bundle.getString("27" );
        String valor28 = bundle.getString("28" );
        String valor29 = bundle.getString("29" );
        String valor30 = bundle.getString("30" );
        String valor31 = bundle.getString("31" );





        textView3.setText((valor1 + "\n" +valor2 + "\n\n" + valor3 + "\n" + valor4 + "\n" + valor5 + "\n" +
                "Votre voyage est prevu pour le:" + valor6 + "\n" +valor7 + "\n" + valor8 + "\n" + valor9 + "\n" + valor10 + "\n" +
                valor11 + "\n" + valor12 + "\n" + valor13 + "\n\n" + valor14 + "\n\n" + valor15 + "\n\n" +
                valor16 + "\n" + valor17 + "\n" + valor18 + "\n" + valor19 + "\n" + valor20 + "\n" +
                valor21 + "\n" + valor22 + "\n\n" + valor23 + "\n" + valor24 + "\n" + valor24 + "\n" +
                valor25 + "\n" + valor26 + "\n" + valor27 + "\n" + valor28 + "\n" + valor28 + "\n\n" +
                valor29 + "\n\n" + valor30 + "\n" + valor31));




    }
}
```

Aqui el xml de la class que recibe los intent.putExtras:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activities.ConcatenacionActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Verifiez_si_toutes_les_donnees_sont_correctes"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/vert_fonce"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/racing_sans_one"
                android:textColor="@color/noir_peu_fonce"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnConfirmationDoneesAchats"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible"

                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="@string/Continuez" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDechargeTicket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/Obtenez_votre_ticket_de_confirmation" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que obtienes es relacionado a que no puedes llamar el método de una vista con valor null

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null
> object reference

El problema es que desde una clase tratas de obtener el valor que se encuentra en los `EditText` de otra activity lo cual es incorrecto.

```
                intent = new Intent(context, FinalActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("1", DonneesDeAcheteurActivity.textViewNom.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("2", DonneesDeAcheteurActivity.textViewPhone.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("3", AgenceDepartActivity.textView.getText().toString());
                ...
                ...
                ...
```

Deberías agregar estos EditText dentro del layout de la activity ServiceSuplementaireActivity que contiene tu RecyclerView.

Comment: lo que quiero es captar los textView.setText() de otras acitividades porqué algunos son resultados de seleccciones de elementos y otros los textView.setText() de EditText(). Algunas maneras de hacerlo?